# Pandas df to lists and sublists

Tags: pandas, dataframe, reduce

I have a pandas data frame with one column and 100 rows(each cell is a paragraph). I would like to create a list of sublists to perform LDA and get the topics. 
Ex:

```
    S.No  Text 
    0      abc 
    1      def 
    2      ghi 
    3      jkl 
    4      mno
```

I want the result to be a list of sublists

```
                         "[[abc]
                           [def]
                           [ghi] 
                           [jkl]
                           [mno]]"
```

So that I can tokenize the sentences into words and perform LDA

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need list of sublist to convert your sentences into tokens. You can do this way (below). Further you can modify from here, whatever way you want the output:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

# example
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['how are you','paris is good','fish is in water','we play tomorrow']})

# tokenize sentences
df['token_text'] = df.text.apply(word_tokenize)

print(df)

    text                 token_text
0   how are you         [how, are, you]
1   paris is good       [paris, is, good]
2   fish is in water    [fish, is, in, water]
3   we play tomorrow    [we, play, tomorrow]
```

Answer (score 0):

YOLO's answer is very good an my be what you're looking for. alternatively if you are trying to use [LDA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html) and want the "list of sublists" it may be better to use arrays which will work on any numpy function. To do so you can just us:

```
df.values
```

of if you only want specific columns you could do

```
df.loc[:, [col1, col2]].values
```

If you must have them as a list of lists then you can do

```
[list(x) for x in df.values]
```